# Filtering array on the basis of click of select button

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, angular10

I have a array as follows -

```
[
{
  "id":1,
  "active":1,
  "name":"paris"
},
{
  "id":2,
  "active":0,
  "name":"london"
},
{
  "id":3,
  "active":1,
  "name":"Australia"
},
{
  "id":4,
  "active":0,
  "name":"india"
}
]
```

I have a select button as follows:

stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-gjxdgy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

code -

```
<h5>Multiple Selection</h5>
<p-selectButton
  [options]="paymentOptions"
  [(ngModel)]="value2"
  multiple="multiple"
  optionLabel="name"
  optionValue="value"
></p-selectButton>
```

component -

```
 this.paymentOptions = [
      { name: 'Option 1', value: 1 },
      { name: 'Option 2', value: 2 }
    ];
```

I want to filter array such data, when `'Option 1'` is clicked, then all the elements with `'active':1` should be present in array. If user unselects `'option 1'`, then array should have all the elements. If `'Option 2'` is clicked, then array should have only elements with `'active':0`, If user unselects `'Option 2'` then array should have all the elements. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your selection to component via `ngModelChange` and use it to run a filter on your array to get the desired result.

app.component.html (added some extra code to show the matching values):

```
<h5>Multiple Selection</h5>
<p-selectButton
  [options]="paymentOptions"
  [(ngModel)]="value2"
  (ngModelChange)="filter($event)"
  multiple="multiple"
  optionLabel="name"
  optionValue="value"
></p-selectButton>

<div>Selected option: {{value2}}</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">{{ item.name}}</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
filter(data) {

    if (data.length === 0) {
      this.filteredItems = this.list;
      return;
    }

    this.filteredItems = [];

    this.filteredItems = this.list.filter(
      (item) => data.findIndex((x) => (x === item.active && x !== 2) || (item.active === 0 && x === 2)) > -1
    );
}
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-selectbutton-demo-qqrpzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: your code not working for option 2. If I select option2 it is showing nothing. For option 1 it is fine

Comment: "active":0 one's should come on click of option2

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that part of the question. I have updated the answer and stackblitz

Comment: Done with all the edits, wanted to get to the most efficient answer I can think of :)

Comment: But when I unselect option 1 or option 2 it should show all the elements of array. In your code on unselected it is showing nothing

Comment: You just need to check if length is 0, then assign the list the filter variable. I have updated the answer and sb.